# How to compress Camel HTTP responses?

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Camel's [REST endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html) to implement HTTP endpoints. I want to enable HTTP payload compression on the responses, but haven't found a way to achieve it. If I add a `marshall().gzip()` bit to the routes, it does compress the payload but I end up with a compressed file instead!

Did anyone manage to implement HTTP compression in Camel?

Thank you!

AP

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which http component you use for the rest component, then they may support automatic compression if you set the `content-encoding` header to be gzip compressed. For the jetty ought to support this.

There is a standard http syntax for that, usually that the `content-encoding` header has the word `gzip` included.

Camel uses this util method to determine that: org.apache.camel.util.GZIPHelper#isGzip(org.apache.camel.Message)